# Fix hyphenated words from line continuance in txt file

Tags: text-processing

I have dozens of large txt files (newspaper articles) and thousands of hyphenations from words continuing onto the next line in the newspaper. There is a hyphen and a space then the rest of the word, like these two examples:

> One possibility for United Nations ac- tion
>
> And it would probably seek to block inclu- sion of the issue

Some pointers on how to fix these?

Comment: `sed -i 's/- //g' *.txt`

Comment: thank you @SatōKatsura but I get this when I try that solution: sed: -i may not be used with stdin

Answer (score 4):

```
sed 's/\([[:alpha:]]\)- \([[:alpha:]]\)/\1\2/g' < file.txt > file-processed.txt
```

Replaces `<letter1>- <letter2>` with `<letter1><letter2>`.

That's less aggressive than `sed 's/- //g'` which could replace other usages of the hyphen like in `13 - 4 = 9`